# Why inverted color changes to italic font in terminal

Tags: linux, terminal

I ssh/mosh into two servers with the same settings (to my best knowledge).

However, when the output is in inverted color (background color <=> front color) on server A, it's shown as italic font on B. This happens to all built in command. For example,

`cal`

[image]

The current date shows in inverted color, but in server B:

[image]

I have tried hard to figure out what's the difference between the two servers but no avail.

It seems not related to my ssh, centos or terminal (zsh) settings.

Comment: This mentions the reason for your problem: [Why does tmux set TERM variable to screen?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/240146/why-does-tmux-set-term-variable-to-screen)

Comment: @ThomasDickey, you are right, it seems related to my tmux, and the problem happens on tmux 3.0a - my TERM=screen-256color

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/891336/fixed-highlighting-in-tmux

Comment: was able to fix in tmux.conf:  `set -ga terminal-overrides ",xterm-*:sitm@:ritm@"`

Answer (score 8):

The "inverted color" is the terminal's **standout** capability, normally done using reverse-video (colors don't matter).  A program running in `screen` may send the escape sequence for **standout**, but `screen` program happens to interpret the standard escape sequence for **italics** as the **standout** feature.  [So it sends italics](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/240147/105132).

If you're not actually using `screen`, you're using some program which copied that (mis)feature.

Addressing a comment: tmux began by using the terminal description designed for GNU screen, which has this italics sequence as the standout capability.  Later versions of tmux look first for a description designed for tmux.  You can see the feature using infocmp:

```
$ infocmp screen tmux    
comparing screen to tmux.
    comparing booleans.
    hs: F:T.
    comparing numbers.
    ncv: NULL, NULL.
    comparing strings.
    dsl: NULL, '\E]0;\007'.
    fsl: NULL, '^G'.
...
    kri: NULL, '\E[1;2A'.
    ritm: NULL, '\E[23m'.
    rmso: '\E[23m', '\E[27m'.
    sgr: '\E[0%?%p6%t;1%;%?%p1%t;3%;%?%p2%t;4%;%?%p3%t;7%;%?%p4%t;5%;%?%p5%t;2%;m%?%p9%t\016%e\017%;', '\E[0%?%p6%t;1%;%?%p2%t;4%;%?%p1%p3%|%t;7%;%?%p4%t;5%;%?%p5%t;2%;%?%p7%t;8%;m%?%p9%t\016%e\017%;'.
    sitm: NULL, '\E[3m'.
    smso: '\E[3m', '\E[7m'.
    tsl: NULL, '\E]0;'.
```

`smso` is the *standout* capability, while `sitm` and `ritm` set/reset italics.

Comment: my term is `screen-256color` and it seems that TMUX changed the behavior after version 2.x -> 3.0

Answer (score 0):

Check the TERM environment variable on both servers.

Check the corresponding setting in the terminal application if you are using saved profiles for different connections.