# Why is tmux ignoring the `default-terminal` setting?

Tags: tmux

I would like to get italic fonts working correctly inside tmux, as currently they only work outside of it. Research suggests this might be accomplished by setting the `default_terminal` setting so I have the below in my tmux.conf. This doesn't seem to accomplish anything however. My understanding is this should set $TERM, but this is still set to `screen`. Even if I run tmux prefaced with `TERM=tmux-256color`, it immediately sets it back to `screen`. What's going on here?

```
set -g default-terminal "tmux-256color"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does tmux set TERM variable to screen?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/240146/why-does-tmux-set-term-variable-to-screen)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that terminal database for `screen` and its derivatives like `screen-256color` simply do not declare any support for italic text, this may be evident with e.g.:

```bash
tput sitm | xxd
```

...which prints *nothing*, meaning there isn't any escape sequence that will instruct your terminal (when it declares itself to be `screen`-like) to switch to italic mode when asked.

The database for the `tmux` `TERM` identifier, however, on a RHEL 9 host at least, does support italic mode, because the above command line will print:

```
00000000: 1b5b 336d                                .[3m
```

Subsequently, the support can be tested with:

```bash
echo $(tput sitm) test $(tput sgr0)
```

, where the text "test" should be printed in italic.

`sitm` is the terminal-invariant option to `tput` to generate the necessary escape sequence for switching to italic, while `sgr0` resets color and mode of the text back to default (the "SGR" abbreviation stands for Select Graphic Rendition).

Do *not* set `TERM` in your shell or anywhere except where the terminal emulator can be known, unless you know what you're doing and are sure your system is otherwise broken somehow -- the `TERM` specifies your terminal emulator and the shell cannot possibly know that (well, it could only ever know *through* querying the `TERM` in the first place, right?)

I don't know how many people, for how many years, must have warned against setting `TERM` in all the wrong places (which are, really, *all* of the places), but it's still being proliferated on the Internet, as can be plainly seen. Just avoid setting `TERM` for as long and longer than you possibly can, chances are it will break something, unless you are absolulutely, positively, cross-your-heart sure you only ever use one terminal emulator. Which you don't. Besides, like I said, if you need to set `TERM`, something is broken somewhere in your system, which would be odd for a sufficiently modern operating system, unless you broke something there in the first place.

In a similar vein, do not set tmux's `default-terminal` option to anything else but `screen` or `tmux` or their derivatives (`{screen,tmux}{.,-}*`), there is a very good reason the manual pages of `tmux` warn you against it:

> For tmux to work correctly, this *must* be set to ‘screen’, ‘tmux’ or a derivative of them.

Tmux is *not* "Xterm", so if you think you've gotten away with `set-option default-terminal xterm-256color` or perhaps some form of `set-option terminal-overrides ...`, you most likely are waiting for a slew of issues to crop up, which may force you to re-think the "hack". Depending on what you're doing in the terminal, correct rendering will be subtly broken without requiring even more hacks to "correct" the first hack and so on.

I suspect the reason `tmux` uses `screen` as `TERM` by default, is because at the time `screen` was prevalent and the terminfo database supported it (and not `tmux` which was a novelty). Today I suspect many distributions support `tmux` explicitly, so `set-option default-terminal tmux` (or a derivative like `tmux-256color`, depending on installed terminfo database) may be exactly what you need, no more but no less.

Answer (score 0):

I may be late, but this may help whoever lands here. I had this issue and also some others around setting truecolors, I'm also still learning this stuff so I am probably going to mix multiple fixes, but below is some info/steps I did to set it to `tmux-256color` and also have truecolor working correctly.

1. It's not advisable to change the `TERM` var from your alacritty config. You should do it on your `.tmux.conf` file.
2. An important detail about tmux that I figured after some hours is that it seems some configs won't reload unless you **kill all your sessions**. So, when trying new stuff or fixes, work under a session and kill it every time you want to reload to guarantee the changes take effect *i.e. a (tmux new / :kill-session) workflow*.
3. Before setting my default-terminal to `tmux-256color` I did 2 things. (this is where I am currently discovering if this part was really relevant or just point 2 where we have to kill sessions)

- set an `alias tmux="tmux -2"`
- get terminfo profiles for tmux-256color: `sudo apt install ncurses-term`

4. I have tmux 3.2 and I am setting my terminal and features like so:

```
set -g default-terminal "tmux-256color" 
set -as terminal-features ",xterm-256color:RGB"
```

Anyway point 3 and 4 may not be too relevant for your issue, so point 2 may be the reason. But I'll leave 3 and 4 for anyone who may face this next challenge.